# how to show button and images in one line using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$('#needdiv').append('<img src="/images/Connect.png" id="connectimage">' + '</img>'
        + '<input type="button" id="connect" value=connect >' + '</input>'
        + '<img src="/images/Remove.png" id="removeimage" />'
        + '<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove">'+'</input>');
```

And in my HTML page there is:

```
<div id=needdiv></div>
```

this is the css

```
  #connectimage      
  {float:left;      
  vertical-align:left;
  }
  #connect
  { text-decoration:none;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
  #removeimage
  {
  vertical-align:middle;
  }

  #remove
  {
  vertical-align:right;
  }
```

How can I show this image and button in a single line? I want `connect image` in left side, `connect button` and `remove image` in middle, `remove button` in right. But all in single line.

Comment: try using html `<table>` with `table-layout: fixed` so you can accurately define the widths of the cells.

Comment: Provide CSS and HTML + a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please specify your problem correctly , upload an image of what you want to acquire? What you mean by "connect image in left side, connect button and remove image in middle, remove button in right" . Middle and left of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First you put one Div element for whole content set width as 100%
and indise div for img tag 50% and Button 50% .It should work


CSS:

#needdiv
{
width:100%;
display:block;
}

 #needdiv img
{
float:left;
}
 #needdiv input
{
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted all your elements to display side by side like that, you can apply a CSS style to all of them and use the float property (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2rRa/):

```
#needdiv img, #needdiv input {
    float: left;
}
```

Or, you could also use the display property (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G2rRa/1/):

```
#needdiv img, #needdiv input {
    display: inline;
}
```

You can use the CSS margin property to adjust to spacing between your elements:

```
#needdiv img, #needdiv input {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```